# How to obtain a proper C# string array from a JavaScript function call using Jint

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, casting, jint

I'm using Jint to evaluate JavaScript within a C# application. My JS returns an array of strings:

```
return ["blah", "blah", "blah"];
```

But I'm not sure how to properly use that array once I'm back in C#:

```
Object result = e.Execute (javaScript).Invoke("jsFunction", answers).ToObject();
string[] resultAsStrings = ???;
```

Here's what the debugger looks like:

[image]

Comment: using the debugger, what does `result` look like when you step past that line.. I assume from there you want to assign `var resultAsStrings = result`

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast the result of `ToObject()` to an `object[]` in this case.

Here are the transformations that `ToObject()` applies when facing a JavaScript value:

- `undefined`: `null`
- `null`: `null`
- `Boolean`: `bool`
- `String`: `string`
- `Number`: `double`
- `Array`: `object[]` with each element itself converted using `ToObject()`
- `Date`: `DateTime`
- `Function`: `Func<JsValue, JsValue[], JsValue>`
- `RegExp`: `Regex`
- `Object`: `dynamic` with all the properties of the object converted using `ToObject()`

If no type is matching, it throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`